# push notifications Genexus

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

This is my first question, and don't wanna be the last one. I need to know how to register the device from the phone to the register service in order to have enabled the push notifications in Genexus.

Answer (score 2):

When you have push notifications enabled on your SD application, the application automatically calls the procedure NotificationsRegistrationHandler, here you have to handle the registration of your device on your notifications provider (for example onesignal)

Comment: Now, the problem I have, is that I can't get the device information that returns from the NotificationsRegistrationHandler, the device is well registered in the one signal portal. So I hope anybody can help me.

Comment: Please, be more specific about what information do you need and where you need it. NotificationsRegistrationHandler won't return anything, it's just for registration.

Comment: In that cause, How can I get the OneSignal UID registrationID, so I can send notifications later??.

Comment: In this link you can see how you register the oneSignal id in the notificationsregistrationhandler https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18149,HowTo%3A%20Using%20Devices%20Registration%20Service%20for%20Push%20Notifications 

Once you have the id in your database you can retrieve it later in order to send the notifications.

Comment: Is there other configuration that I need to do in order to make this working??because I am following the steps in the below tutorial and it still not working, I can`t retrieve the info of the OneSignal UID.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to have Push Notifications up and running with GeneXus, is using GeneXus OneSignal implementation.

Take a look [here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?30621,HowTo%3A%20Push%20Notifications%20Using%20OneSignal)